# Retrieve a Chat Log watson assistant

Tags: ibm-watson, watson-conversation

I'm using Watson Assistant and Cloud Function in a basic chatbot. How can i retrieve via Cloud Function (node.js) the chatlog of a specific conversation? I'd like to implement this user functionality. So for example, if the user types "Chat Log", Watson Assistant send him back (via Cloud Function) his chatlog. Thanks.

Comment: have you looked at the node.js sdk?

Answer (score 1):

In case you are using v1 version of the Watson Assistant(WA), you will get the logs via the API: https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/assistant/assistant-v1#listlogs

In case you are using v2 version of the Watson Assistant(WA), you will get the logs via the API: https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/assistant/assistant-v2#listlogs

In both of these versions, you will find a filter parameter which can be set to the current chat conversation ID or session ID and could be used to get the chat log.

Answer (score 0):

Now there is a REST API that allows to get the user conversations - however this gets all users conversations so you would need to implement some kind of a proxy that would filter these logs anyway.

For this particular use case, I believe, it would be the best to log the conversations into a separate database where the data would be organized by user id. First of all - separate results for particular user can be achieved easilly in this case, second of all - in IBM Cloud in Watson Assistant the chat logs are kept for 30 days - that might not be enough for this kind of functionality.